# Updating Listview in Viewpager works until switching to last fragment and back

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've been trying to update a listview on my second position of a viewpager when checking a "favourite" checkbox on the listview using an interface. It's working as expected but when I go to the 3rd Fragment and then swipe back again the favourites doesn't update even though everything seems like it should work as before doesn't work until i rotate or restart the app.

I've checked the fragmentmanager and it does contain only three Fragments all the time and the methods do get called (register as if the listview should be changed like it does before i swipe to the 3rd tab and back), so I'm really scratching my head here.

FragmentStatePageAdapter:

```
    SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();
    /* Some irrelevant code */

   @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return FragmentList.newInstance();
        case 1:
            return FragmentFavourites.newInstance();
        case 2:
            return FragmentThree.newInstance();
        default:
            return FragmentList.newInstance();
    }
}
     @Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    registeredFragments.remove(position);
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}

public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
    return registeredFragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
```

Activity (callback):

```
     @Override
public void favouritesChangedFromMainMenu() {
    FragmentFavourites favouritesList = (FragmentFavourites) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(1);
    if(null != favouritesList) {
        favouritesList.favouritesChangedFromMainMenu();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you move to the third fragment, the first one is probably killed (with a call to `onSaveInstanceState`).

**Solution 1**, `yourViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);`

**Solution 2**, check if your first fragment is killed... and re-created when you swipe and re-create correct link that you do in `onCreate`.

Comment: Haven't tried it but offscreenpagelimit will most certainly fix it. The fragment do get destroyed but I update my SparseArray when this happens, if you could elaborate on your second solution that would be great because I don't fully understand what you mean